# Can't push to GitLab

Tags: git, ubuntu, push, server, gitlab

I just finished setting up GitLab on my Ubuntu Server last night, but it looks like I can't push anything to it. I'm extremely new to Git, so I really don't know what I'm doing here.

Here's my output from SourceTree when I try to push:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master
POST git-receive-pack (475 bytes)

remote: GitLab: API is not accessible[K

Pushing to http://git.ghostlyco.de/revxx14/new-site.git
To http://git.ghostlyco.de/revxx14/new-site.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://git.ghostlyco.de/revxx14/new-site.git'




Completed with errors, see above.
```

No idea what this means. I was able to pull the thing just fine, so I'm really confused.

Here's the output when I run `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`:

http://git.ghostlyco.de/snippets/1

The only thing I can think of that's out of the ordinary for this install was that I couldn't run this command: `echo 'unixsocketperm 770' | sudo tee -a /etc/redis/redis.conf` because [the version of Redis that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x86 doesn't support `unixsocketperm`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/192#note_286271). Not sure if that could be causing this issue.

---

`git remote -v` output:

```
origin  http://git.ghostlyco.de/revxx14/new-site.git (fetch)
origin  http://git.ghostlyco.de/revxx14/new-site.git (push)
```

Comment: Have you set up a custom receive hook for that repo?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that is. I'm completely new to all this. All I did was click "New Project" in the web client for GitLab.and fill out that information, I'm guessing no.

Comment: Are you sure the user "git" has the proper permission (write in particular) for the repositories directory?

Comment: I followed the directions here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md I'm thinking step 6, `# Make sure GitLab can write to the log/ and tmp/ directories`, covers that, which I did. Is there something else I have to chown? I'm running everything exactly as that link instructs me to if that helps.

Comment: Did you also try creating another project and push to that? I've found that the gitlab demons sometimes like to play pranks on us mere mortals...

Comment: Gave that a shot, same issue.

Comment: Did you just do a `git push -u origin master`?

Comment: I'm not using command line, I'm using SourceTree, so I don't know. I'm just getting started with Git so I don't know much about it yet. I also tried using the GitHub Client application with my custom server but I get a generic "there was an error" when trying to publish, so I think it's the same issue.

Comment: Have you initialized the repository properly locally?

Comment: I think so, the .git folder is there and everything. I just tried deleting the repo and doing things from scratch using the command line with the instructions GitLab provides, and that gave me the the exact same error.

Comment: Added a link to a snippet at the end of my question that might be helpful.

Comment: What does `git remote -v` output?

Comment: Could you try pushing over ssh instead?

Comment: Just ried to do that, but I keep getting permission denied errors for some reason. I try to enter my password and it won't take. Not sure what the deal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I had forgot to set gitlab_url in config.yml.